# beanstalk using php-git on windows client

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, amazon-beanstalk

I am trying to install beanstalk for php using git. I am using a Windows Client machine. I am done with the prerequisite installations , credentials setup. I am following the link

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.sdlc.html

The following step does not workout (i use git bash for git related commands)

From your Git repository directory, type the following command.

```
git aws.config
```

This gives the error

```
git : 'aws.config' is not a git command.
```

Please suggest how to deal with the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you haven't set up [AWS DevTools](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/GettingStarted.GetSetup-devtools.html) yet, which provide the AWS specific Git commands, including `aws.config`:

> AWS DevTools is a Git client extension that enables you to deploy
>   applications to AWS Elastic Beanstalk quickly. This section describes
>   the prerequisites for running AWS DevTools, where to get it, and how
>   to set it up.

So you'll simply need to set up this Git client extension according to the steps detailed on that page and should be on track.

Comment: i have installed aws dev tools, there was a batch file for one time setup and it executed without any errors. The git on my system is by default accessible by git bash only, not through the windows command prompt . Can this be an issue?

Comment: @ntidote: Have you executed the per repository setup batch file as well (quote: _You need to run this script for each Git repository._)?